# Two-way mapping between strings and integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a collection of pairs of strings and (non-contiguous) integers, which are known in advance, a Python dictionary literal is a straightforward way to define a mapping from either to the other.

But supposing some parts of your program will have a string and want the corresponding integer, and others will have an integer and want the corresponding string, what's the best way to arrange this? Of course I could write out two separate dictionary literals, but that violates DRY, or I could do a bit of hacking with a function that uses globals() to create two dictionary variables from a single set of inputs, but I'm not sure how idiomatic that is. What's the recommended way? (I'm using Python 2.7 if it matters.)

Comment: as this is obviously a kind of enum type, have you looked at the various enum implementations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the second mapping automatically from the first:

```
d2 = {v:k for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use bidict https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a pair of `dict`s, why not use an `enum`?

Of course the stdlib [`enum`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html) module requires 3.4, but its [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/enum.py) is available to read and backport, or you can get the semi-official [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34/0.9.19) off PyPI, or any of the dozens of other [`enum` packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=enum&submit=search).

For example:

```
>>> import enum
>>> class Color(enum.Enum):
...     red = 1
...     green = 2
...     blue = 3
>>> Color.red
<Color.red: 1>
>>> Color['red']
<Color.red: 1>
>>> Color(1)
<Color.red: 1>
>>> Color(1).name
'red'
>>> Color['red'].value
1
```

My guess is, most of the time you won't actually be mapping back and forth between these, but just using `Color.red`, instead of your current `"red"` or `1`, as a value. (If you want to be able to use the value directly as either an `int` or a `str`, look at the other classes in the docs.)

There should be good examples all over the 3.4 stdlib of how to convert code that used to use numbers and map them to strings and vice-versa into code that uses `Enum`s instead. Unfortunately, as of 3.4b1, most of those examples haven't been written yet… I believe [`socket.AddressFamily`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/socket.py#l64) and a few related types are the only ones that have made it so far. But if you can't figure it out, show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and it should be easy to show you how to convert it.

Comment: That looks good actually, but when I download and unpack the .tar.gz, enum.py is 0 bytes even though the rest of the files in the package seem to be okay?

Comment: @rwallace: I just installed it with `pip install enum34` and everything worked… let me check doing it your way.

Comment: @rwallace: OK, `enum.py` is not an empty file, but a symlink to `enum/__init__.py`. This is a trick that some packages use to make the same code work directly out of the source directory as well as when installed. (It's not a common trick, because it only works when the package has nothing but `__init__.py` in it, in which case you didn't really need a package anyway…) The trick probably only works on Unix. But anyway, don't worry about it; install the package your favorite way (which should be `pip`, but if not, that's fine…) and everything will be OK.

Comment: Okay, I tried copying `enum/__init__.py` to `enum.py` in my project directory and the contents thereof look okay, but whether I `import enum` or `from enum import Enum` it says it can't find the name `Enum`, what am I still missing?

Comment: @rwallace: Do you not know how to install packages? You almost never want to try to copy them into your project. Just install them into your (system, user, or virtualenv) site-packages the normal way, and everything will work.

Comment: @rwallace: If you don't know how to install packages, see [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html). But at the moment (early 2014) it's being rewritten, so just look at the note at the top that says "Refer to the [quick recommendations section](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) in the Python Packaging User Guide for more information", which will basically tell you to install and use `pip`.

Comment: Sure, if you're writing something that just has to run on your own machine; or perhaps the custom on Unix is to do things that way regardless. I'm on Windows, writing a program intended for distribution, so it needs to be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: @rwallace: The standard way to do that is to use a tool like `cx_Freeze`, `py2exe`, `pyInstaller`, etc., or just a `bdist_installer`, so you can create a binary application or MSI installer for distribution. Otherwise, you're relying on everyone having the same version of Python as you (and, if you have any C extension modules, they'll also need the exact same versions of whatever DLLs those depend on, and so on).

Comment: @rwallace: For examples, see [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard), the original BitTorrent Mainline, [QuodLibet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/), etc. While some of them distribute source with a list of requirements on Linux, _all_ of them distribute a pre-built binary on Windows, and _none_ of them distribute source with third-party projects copied into the middle of the project.

Comment: Yep, packaging a standalone binary is on my to-do list; orthogonally, I'm trying to keep the requirements for compiling the program as close as possible to 'out-of-the-box Python 2.7'. If enum isn't compatible with that setup, fair enough.

Comment: @rwallace: `enum` _might_ be, but _most_ packages are not, so you shouldn't be surprised if it isn't. Sometimes you can reorganize the code to make it work, or even just copy-paste things into your own files and remove all the qualified names, but when you go against the standard way to do things, you're creating more work for yourself.